# Multiline property problems

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2010

I have a column in my database that is set to memo. I am trying to view the data in a textbox.

I have enabled ***new line in field*** from the Enter Key Behaviour property but all the data from the record is now showing - What am I missing?

The data is being pulled from a list box, example code below:

```
Textbox1 = listbox.column(1)
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

This has nothing to do with the `EnterKeyBehavior` property of the text box.

http://allenbrowne.com/ser-63.html

> **Row Source**
>
> A Memo field in the Row Source of a combo box or list box will
>   truncate.
>
> Don't use memo fields in combos or list boxes.

You'll need a different method to load the text box, e.g. read the ID from the listbox and use `DLookup()`.