# Access 2007 Form : Unbound text box : Memo field truncated

Tags: ms-access-2007

I have a table with a memo field to hold descriptive notes. In a form I have a combo box whose data source query includes this memo field. After update of this combo box I set an unbound text box on the form to the appropriate column number from the combo box.

The memo field is truncated (probably to 255 chars). How can I get the whole memo field to display in the unbound text box?

It is the SQL that is truncating the field. I've tried setting it from a recordset collection but as that's also based on SQL the truncation also occurs.

This seems to be a relatively common problem but I've not been able to find a workaround anywhere.

Thanks in advance for any helpful suggestions...

Comment: This is a good start : http://allenbrowne.com/ser-63.html. If you can't find an answer there, show the query

Comment: Hi Thomas. Yes, I'd seen the AllenBrowne document although it doesn't help much. The combo box data source query is very straightforward - just columns selected from a single table :"SELECT ACReportType.ACRT_ID, ACReportType.ACRT_Description, ACReportType.ACRT_VBReportName, ACReportType.ACRT_Notes
FROM ACReportType
ORDER BY ACReportType.ACRT_Description;
"

Comment: I've also tried setting the form's RecordSource to the ACReportType table and adding the problematic memo field from the list from 'Add Existing Fields' but it still truncates. I've compared the field format etc. to its equivalent on the ACReportType maintenance form (where the memo field behaves 'properly') and I can't see any difference.

Comment: This query is the comboboix record source, and then you are trying to move the memo data in the combobox to another textbox? right ? if yes, search no longer your data is truncated in the combobox and you can't change that. You will have to make an additional query to retrieve the whole memo field, after the user select something in the combobox

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/47762509/3820271

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One method is to use *DLookup* in the *AfterUpdate* event of the combobox:

```
Me!YourTextbox.Value = DLookup("[MemoField]", "YourTable", "ID =" & Me!YourCombobox.Value & "")
```

assuming the combobox is bound to field ID. Otherwise, use the column of the combobox that holds the ID to look up.

Comment: Thanks Gustav. 'DLookup' is new to me (...wish I'd known about it a long time ago !) and it retrieves the memo field but it is still truncated. It must be something  to do with the text box definition. I'll have a tinker...

Comment: Aaah... at some point during my messing about  / diagnostic experimentation the actual memo field got truncated. The 'Dlookup' thing works perfectly. Also an incredibly useful function in general  - I assume it is more efficient that using a recordset to retrieve single field values; it is certainly tidier ! Thanks again Gustav.